# Select Distinct Records from the table

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I would like to write a Query by selecting the dataset from the below image
The dataset is from `migration_data_temp table`

[image]

I Want the Data to be like the below Image which will populate the actual table `migration_data`, Note even though the name is `migration_data_temp` its not a `GTT`, consider it as a Staging table

[image]

I tried  Analytical Function but no luck, also I Tried with SELECT Distinct option too..

**Table script**

```
CREATE TABLE RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP
(
  ID             NUMBER         GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME           VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  TEMPLATE_NAME  VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  PARENT_NAME    VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  PORT_OF_ENTRY  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
)


Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME)Values (1, 'TN - People - 2019- Mode of Migration', 'Mode of Migration Template');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(2, '2 Migration', '2 Migration', 'TN - People - 2019- Mode of Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(3, '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2 Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(4, '2.2.T Transportation', '2.2.T Transportation', '2.2 Mode of Migration', 'NY');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values (5, '2.2.T.1 Air', '2.2.T.1 Air', '2.2.T Transportation', 'NY');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(6, '2.2.T.1.1 American Airways', '2.2.T.1.1 American Airways', '2.2.T.1 Air', 'NY');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(7, '2.2.T.1.2 Southwest Airlines', '2.2.T.1.2 Southwest Airlines', '2.2.T.1 Air', 'NY');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(8, '2.2.T.1.3 Spirit Airlines', '2.2.T.1.3 Spirit Airlines', '2.2.T.1 Air', 'NY');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(9, '2.2.T.1.4 Allegiant Airlines', '2.2.T.1.4 Allegiant Airlines', '2.2.T.1 Air', 'NY');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(10, '2 Migration', '2 Migration', 'TN - People - 2019- Mode of Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(11, '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2 Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(12, '2.2.T.2 Rail', '2.2.T.2 Rail', '2.2.T Transportation', 'IL');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(13, '2.2.T.2.1 Amtrak', '2.2.T.2.1 Amtrak', '2.2.T.2 Rail', 'IL');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(14, '2.2.T.2.2 Metro Train', '2.2.T.2.2 Metro Train', '2.2.T.2 Rail', 'IL');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(15, '2.2.T.2.3 Path Transfer', '2.2.T.2.3 Path Transfer', '2.2.T.2 Rail', 'IL');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(16, '2 Migration', '2 Migration', 'TN - People - 2019- Mode of Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(17, '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2 Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(18, '2.2.T.3 Road', '2.2.T.3 Road', '2.2.T Transportation', 'CA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(19, '2.2.T.3.1 Car', '2.2.T.3.1 Car', '2.2.T.3 Road', 'CA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(20, '2.2.T.3.2 Bike', '2.2.T.3.2 Bike', '2.2.T.3 Road', 'CA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(21, '2.2.T.3.3 Cycle', '2.2.T.3.3 Cycle', '2.2.T.3 Road', 'CA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(22, '2.2.T.3.4 Walking', '2.2.T.3.4 Walking', '2.2.T.3 Road', 'CA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(23, '2 Migration', '2 Migration', 'TN - People - 2019- Mode of Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME)Values(24, '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2.2 Mode of Migration', '2 Migration');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(25, '2.2.T.4 Sea', '2.2.T.4 Sea', '2.2.T Transportation', 'VA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(26, '2.2.T.4.1 Boat', '2.2.T.4.1 Boat', '2.2.T.4 Sea', 'VA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(27, '2.2.T.4.2  Ship', '2.2.T.4.2  Ship', '2.2.T.4 Sea', 'VA');
Insert into RIM_API_USER.MIGRATION_DATA_TEMP(ID, NAME, TEMPLATE_NAME, PARENT_NAME, PORT_OF_ENTRY)Values(28, '2.2.T.4.3 yacht', '2.2.T.4.3 yacht', '2.2.T.4 Sea', 'VA');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I am sorry I tried many ways to Format the Code, I am not able to thanks

Comment: @Maheswran Ravishankar, Thanks a Lot for Formatting, Appreciate your Help

Comment: All formatting options are explained if you click on the `?` button in the toolbar when editing your question. It will eventually lead you to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.template_name, a.parent_name, a.port_of_entry
from (
select t.*, 
row_number() over (partition by t.name, t.template_name, t.parent_name order by id) rnk
from migration_data_temp t )a
where a.rnk = 1
order by a.id
```

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5eb8b87640ed2f35b540a7913eb277e)

Comment: Thanks for the Solution, it worked appreciate your help

Comment: @vasanthanand You are welcome. Please accept the answer to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Am i guessing it right? Do you want to select multiple columns by applying distinct on one column only? If yes [here](https://bugs.code.blog/2019/03/11/sql-query-multiple-columns-using-distinct-on-one-column-only/) is the solution. If not, tell me precisely

Comment: Also use alias if you want to view the selected columns in a different column

Comment: Solutions thanks for the response, But I was looking for Analytical Query by Gen Wan